# If there is nudity in a movie, do actors have to show their bodies in casting too?

Tags: casting, film-industry

If there is nudity in a show or movie, will the producers/casting directors want to see the actors nude in casting? I guess to "see the merchandise", so to speak?

Answer (score 1):

The answer will have to be "it depends". It's got to depend on the director, the casting director, possible changes to the script, etc.

An interesting case regarding script changes: One draft of the script for *Close Encounters of the Third Kind* included a topless scene with Teri Garr. However, that scene was never shot, and the actress never had to appear nude. She was not asked to appear topless during her audition (as far as I could discover).

Comment: And depends on the type of movie - for any serious movie where the nudity will be about showing something about the character then I guess the answer is almost certainly no.  But an erotic movie, where the nudity is for titillation, that's a different question - I guess it's likely they would ask the actor to provide body photos rather than appearing nude in the casting room.